# Import font library to angular project

Tags: angular

I want to import https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/helvetica-neue-lt-pro-2 this font to my project. I'm using scss on my project. I downloaded font files there are a lot of woff files. How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'xyz';
  src: url(assets/fonts/xyz.woff) format("woff");
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
div {
  font-family: 'xyz';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the font file and extract in the **assets/fonts** folder. the extracted folder itself contains style.css file and you need to import the style file in **angular.json**.

```
"styles": [
     "src/styles.css",
     "src/assets/fonts/helvetica-neue-lt-pro-2-cufonfonts-webfont/style.css"
 ]
```

And it will be applied globally. you just use **font-family** where you need use

Comment: NOT put .css in assets folder and include in angular.json,  Angular gets all the .css in your angular.json and create an unique bundle with them, so it's innnecesary you copy the .css to the assets folder (rememeber that Angular copy all yours files in assets)